# Joining a calendar table to find timesheet missing dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, calendar, sql-server-2012

I have a timesheet query that looks like this:

```
User    TimesheetStart    TimesheetEnd
Allen   2014-07-01        2014-07-15
Allen   2014-08-01        2014-08-15
Allen   2014-08-16        2014-08-31
```

I have a calendar view that looks like this.  The [Date] column defines the first date, the 15th, the 16th, and the last date of the month.

[image: Calendar]

I need a query that returns the following.  I just can't wrap my head around what JOIN i need.  I tried a RIGHT JOIN on calendar view, but isn't working.

```
User    TimesheetStart    TimesheetEnd    TimesheetPeriodBeginning
Allen   2014-07-01        2014-07-15      2014-07-01
Allen   NULL              NULL            2014-07-16
Allen   2014-08-01        2014-08-15      2014-08-01
Allen   2014-08-16        2014-08-31      2014-08-16
Allen   NULL              NULL            2014-09-01
Allen   NULL              NULL            2014-09-16
```

`NULL` would indicate missing timesheet entries.

There's what I have so far:

```
SELECT ts.Fields (truncated for clarity)
    ,calendar.Fields (truncated for clarity)
FROM [dbo].[timesheet] AS ts
--this join isn't working...
RIGHT JOIN [dbo].[v_Timesheet_Periods] AS calendar
ON ts.StartDate = calendar.[Date]
```

[image]

Comment: You have `calendar` alias while in query you use `tsPeriods`

Comment: Also when you say isn't working, what exactly happens? do you get syntax errors or wrong result?

Comment: @Bulat I've edited the question for clarity.  It's not working per screenshot...  The RIGHT JOIN only returns dates that exist in the timesheet table, not the missing dates as well.  not sure why.

Comment: are you sure that you have September dates in v_Timesheet_Periods?

Comment: @Bulat yes.  I have all dates and can filter on any range.  Calendar extends to the year 2020.

Comment: You might have a date filter somewhere beyond this query? do you run it directly against the database?

Comment: @Bulat No, the calendar query is not being filtered at the moment.  Yes, it's running directly against a Calendar table.

Comment: Can you try it with LEFT JOIN.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60718/discussion-between-kkkkkkkk-and-bulat).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your end data overlaps in your join.
And do you need to account for time?
So should you use >= and a < for the end?

```
SELECT ts.Fields (truncated for clarity)
    ,calendar.Fields (truncated for clarity)
FROM [dbo].[timesheet] AS ts
--this join isn't working...
RIGHT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[v_Timesheet_Periods] AS calendar
ON ts.StartDate >= tsPeriods.[Date]
    AND ts.EndDate < tsPeriods.[Date]
```

Comment: I looked at your EndDate field in the screenshot, why is it less than your StartDate?

Comment: I can see the start of your where clause as well. How are you joining your lookup table? If your joining timesheet to the lookup, then applying a where clause to the lookup table, you negating the outer join.